# configuring htaccess directory index file

Tags: php, .htaccess, directoryindex

**Scenario:**
I created this htacces file to redirect subdomains. So far it works.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.net/%1/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

**Problem:**

It forces the server to request an arbitrary `index.php` which doesn't exist. What I do have is `index.html`, so I'm getting:

> `Error 404: /xyz/index.php was not found on this server`

**I tried adding:**

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php [L]
```

But only 1st argument gets accepted, the 2nd gets ignored (why?). AFAIK it should accept either of those as long as either exist.

Comment: Remove the [L] from directoryindex as that's not valid, and DirectoryIndex will always use the the first 1st argument if the 1st one exists. If you have both in the same directory it will always still use the first one. It just goes in order of what is in the list to check to see if it exists or not.

Comment: It doesn't work. As is It only evaluates the 1st argument, and ignores the 2nd. E.g. a directory containing index.php will throw 404. There's only 1 index per directory BTW either HTML, or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
i copy this and work right.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]

    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]

</IfModule>
```

you should change 'public' to your folder.

Comment: Nope. That throws `bad request`